# SAS Translate cell count to specific values

Tags: sas

I have a data set that has a person's name and how many times they scored a 1-10.  For example, Bob scored 7 1s, 8 2s, and 7 4s, but did not receive any other scores.

```
Name 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Bob  7 8 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Hal  9 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want a data set that has a row for Bob that looks like this

```
Bob 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
Hal 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

I'm doing this in SAS by the way.

I know I can write a macro to create variables named score1, score2, ..., scoreN.

I am having trouble populating the cells.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the sample of your original dataset?

Comment: Dmitry-I included a snapshot of what Bob would look like in the original dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such things - changing the structure of the dataset - sometimes easier to do with PROC TRANSPOSE:

```
data have;
    input Name $ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10;
    datalines;
Bob 7 8 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
;
run;

 /*convert original wide dataset into long one*/
proc transpose data=have out=have_long;
    var v:;
    by Name;
run;

data want;
    set have_long;
    substr(_NAME_,1,1)=""; *to get rid of first 'v' in variables' names;
    do i=1 to COL1;
         new_var=_NAME_;
         output;
    end;
    drop _NAME_ COL1 i;
run;

/*convert back to wide dataset*/
proc transpose data=want out=want(drop=_NAME_);
    var new_var;
    by Name;
run;
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Good old proc transpose!  Thank you so much, Dmitry.